# Azure AD B2C - Email verification/approval after sign-up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Would like users to sign-up without email verification(There is an option to disable this in B2C GUI) and an email should be sent with a link that users can click to activate the account. Doesn't look to be possible out of the box. Is there a way to accomplish this while also making sure that the email activation is secure and not prone to brute force attack?

Comment: Not familiar with Azure AD, but generally speaking this is something you build in yourself...

Comment: Check aka.ms/aadb2cdemo. There is a scenario for invitation redemption, if helps.

Answer (score 1):

These some example code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/d62c3f9e573ac8b5a9adc1565c6254f632e2a531/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication).

The repository also contains a good write-up "Implementing an invitation flow" which will help.

The security requirement is achieved by using a signed JWT to transfer the claims.